# TYPO3 Neos: Create own inspector/editor

Tags: typo3, typo3-flow, neoscms

I try to create an own editor for the page panel on the right side. For this I use at beginning the HTML-Editor. This will work so far. After this I tried to adapt it for my package but I'll get always the error from `requirejs`:

```
Error: Script error for: My.Package/Inspector/Editors/MyEditor 
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
```

For two days I tried to find out where the error starts, but fail. Is this warning in the documentation the reason?

> [Adding editors and validators is no fixed API yet, keep an eye on the changelogs if you use this.](http://docs.typo3.org/neos/TYPO3NeosDocumentation/IntegratorGuide/CustomContentElements.html#extending-the-inspector)

To reproduce the error do the following:

- Using TYPO3 Neos version 1.1.0
- Create a package named "My.Package"
- Copy the HTMLEditor to Packages/Application/My.Package/Resources/Public/JavaScript/Inspector/Editors/MyEditor.js
- Define Settings.yaml and NodeTypes.yaml

Settings.yaml:

```
TYPO3:
  Neos:
    userInterface:
      # Register editor
      requireJsPathMapping:
        'My.Package/Inspector/Editors': 'resource://My.Package/Public/JavaScript/Inspector/Editors/'
```

NodeTypes.yaml:

```
'TYPO3.Neos.NodeTypes:Page':
  properties:
    settings:
      type: string
#      defaultValue: '<p>Enter HTML here</p>'
      ui:
        label: 'Settings'
#        reloadIfChanged: TRUE
        inspector:
          group: 'layout'
          editor: 'My.Package/Inspector/Editors/MyEditor'
```

The expected behaviour should be to display the property "Settings" after "Layout for subpages of this page" followed by a button like at the HTML content element.

Comment: Everything above is correct and I've tested it on same neos version.
This error means that file could not be found/opened so:  
1. Flush cache with force  
2. Ensure your path is added `./flow configuration:show --type=Settings | grep -3 requireJsPathMapping`  
3. Ensure that your MyEditor.js has correct rights (chmod) and if it's in correct directory (case sensitive) `http://your.neos/_Resources/Static/Packages/My.Package/JavaScript/Inspector/Editors/MyEditor.js`.

Comment: CRAZY!!! My vendor name is blocked by the AdBlocker. I have already changed it a time ago with another letter, but now its blocking again! W-T-F! sorry :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is, that your example worked the way it was stated, but you had an ad blocker that blocked the request to your custom editor script.